# Finding the max sum of successive random numbers in an array

Tags: c#, algorithm, time-complexity

I have an array of 25 random integers between -100 and 100.

For example my array can look like this:
-10, 23, 19, -11, 3, -9, -8, 4, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, -6, -2, 1, -9, 8, -6, 20, -21, -3, -2, -4, -7

I wish to write a method that receive my array as a parameter, and prints out the following: the first index, the last index, and the sum of the successive elements between them, that will give the possible maximum sum.

For my example the output will be: first index: 1 (value: 23), last index: 19 (value:20), total sum: 177

I don't know how I should deal with this problem. I wrote a code, but it's very complex and unefficient because I used a list to store all the possible sums. 
Can you please show a Pseudo-code for this problem, or code in c#?

Comment: I don't see any code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to keep all the possible sums, as you are only interested in the largest.

Loop throught the combinations, and look for any sum that is larger than what you have so far.

You can make use of the fact that the sum of any range of elements is the sum of the elements excluding the last item plus the last item. I.e you don't need to loop through the elements to calculate each possible sum, because you already have the sum of the range that is one element less:

```
public static void ShowLargestSum(int[] arr) {
  int largest = arr[0], start = 0, end = 0;
  for (int i = 0; i < arr.Length; i++) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int j = i; j < arr.Length; j++) {
      sum += arr[j];
      if (sum > largest) {
        largest = sum;
        start = i;
        end = j;
      }
    }
  }
  Console.WriteLine("first index: {0} (value: {1}), last index: {2} (value:{3}), total sum: {4}", start, arr[start], end, arr[end], largest);
}
```

Execution time on my computer for your example array: 0.17 ms.

Answer (score 1):

This is a well known problem in literature, known (among many other names) as **Maximum Subarray Problem**. 
You can find more infos, and a pseudo code with a possible solution here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem

Since your problem seems to be that of finding a viable algorithm and not implementing it, the following pseudo-code should be enough:

```
def max_subarray(A):
    max_ending_here = max_so_far = 0
    for x in A:
        max_ending_here = max(0, max_ending_here + x)
        max_so_far = max(max_so_far, max_ending_here)
    return max_so_far
```